# Subsetting data frame in R, based on function character parameter

Tags: r, function, if-statement, subset

I need to choose a column in a large data set from CSV.

I have this function. Two character arguments - is name of State and desease name. Based on disease name I need to choose the right column in a large dataset to perform calculations.

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {

  OutcomeData <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
```

Second, I try to assign to variable `OutcomeCol` a value, based on function parameter outcome. Number is a column number in `OutcomeData` dataset corresponding `outcome` parameter.

```
I 
  ## 2 - Hospital.Name
  ## 7 - State
  ## 11 - 30 Day mortality Heart Attack
  ## 17 - 30 Day mortality Heart Failure
  ## 23 - 30 Day mortality Pneumonia

  ## Choose Outcome for filtering data
  if (outcome == "heart attack") {OutcomeCol <- 11}
  if (outcome == "heart failure") {OutcomeCol <- 17}
  if (outcome == "pneumonia") {OutcomeCol<- 23}
  try(if (!exists("OutcomeCol")) {stop("invalid outcome")}, silent = TRUE)
```

But when I try to run function best("TX", "heart failure") nothing happens. If I try to place `print(OutcomeCol)` after if statements - it returns NA.

Where is the error? Maybe there another simply way to perform this action?

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` value or a closing `}`...or you just didn't paste it in full?

Comment: Thank you, @Frank! Yes, this is the part of the function that seems not to work. I've found another way to to this correctly. `mortalityColumn <- c(11, 17, 23)
  lookup <- data.frame(outcomes, mortalityColumn)
  OutcomeCol <- lookup$mortalityColumn[lookup$outcomes %in% outcome]`

Comment: Cool, glad to hear you've figured it out. Yeah, making a lookup table is a good way to go (instead of a sequence of `if`s)

Comment: Yes. I'm learning this tool for my statistics. So first steps are difficult. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found another way - making a lookup table is a good way to go (instead of a sequence of ifs!

```
  mortalityColumn <- c(11, 17, 23) lookup <- data.frame(outcomes, 
  mortalityColumn) OutcomeCol <- lookup$mortalityColumn[lookup$outcomes %in% outcome]
```